# YAMMM equivalent

Tags: video, media-manager

I've long used [YAMMM](http://mikinho.com/yammm/) for pulling metadata and thumbnails of my films/rips now i'm in trouble since switching as i can't seem to find any equivalent, The XBMC scrapers have been a disaster (e.g. I ripped toy story 2, put it in a folder "Toy story 2 (2000) and it pulled everything for toystory 3)

So what apps can you recommend?

Comment: If people are not familiar with YAMMM, i suppose Ember media manager and TV rename to some extent have the same sort of features

Answer (score 2):

When I was using MythTV it seemed to do a reasonably solid job of pulling metadata and thumbnails, even for my Korean soap opera. However I don't really know enough to tell you which sub-package does the actual scraping.